# PodSecurityPolicy blocking Pod creation even though PSP Is not enabled on GKE 1.23

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm getting non-sensical error related to PSP when creating a pod using a KSA on a particular GKE 1.23 Cluster:
podsecuritypolicy: unable to admit pod: []

However, I understand from GKE 1.21, PSP feature was beginning to be deprecated in favour of Pod Security standards.
So I checked if PSP feature is enabled on the cluster and it's not:
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe my-gke-cluster --zone=europe-west4-c | grep -iA 1 podsecuritypolicy

Returns nothing so I assume it's not enabled.
So not sure I don't understand why it's failing to admit the pod when it shouldn't be interfering.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to grep for `podSecurityPolicyConfig` to see if it's enabled on the cluster.

Comment: @GariSingh I did a grep on pod* and still wasn't enabled. But still got the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Kubernetes official doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/08/kubernetes-1-21-release-announcement/#podsecuritypolicy-deprecation) kubernetes 1.21 PodSecurity Policy is deprecated and this is totally removed in kubernetes 1.25.  As per the replacement policy they have published a doc to [migrate from PSP to Pod Security admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/migrate-from-psp/).
For more future enhancements, follow this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/2579)

Or else can also use [Gatekeeper](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies-with-gatekeeper) as a replacement which is what some customers use as well. See this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/policy-compliant-resources) which pairs Gatekeeper with Config Connector to enforce policies for GCP resources.

Comment: This doesn't really answer why I get the error. According to the document, its not enabled as per my original post.